# WriteProcessMemory, program's value + user's input value at the same time

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

There is a program that stores a value in memory, like `100`.  I read that value using `ReadProcessMemory()`:

```
ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)(programBaseAddress + offsetProgramToBaseAdress), &baseAddress, sizeof(baseAddress), NULL);
```

After `ReadProcessMemory()`, `baseaddress` contains `100`.

With this code:

```
int value{};
cin >> value;
WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)(pointsAddress), &value, 4, 0);
```

I can change the value in the other program.

But I don't want to set the other program's value to just any value. I want to add the user's input to that value. I mean, the user inputs a number like `50`, the result should be `150`, not `50`.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)(pointsAddress), &baseAddress + value, 4, 0);
```

Comment: `WriteProcessMemory` needs a memory buffer to copy from.  Declare a new variable, like `decltype(baseAddress) TotalAddress = baseAddress + value;` and then pass `&TotalAddress` to `WriteProcessMemory`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the value first, then add the user's input to the value, then write the value back.  Those are separate operations, don't try to mix them together (ie, `&baseAddress + value` doesn't do what you think it does).

Try something like this instead:

```
int32_t value{};
ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)(programBaseAddress + offsetProgramToBaseAdress), &value, sizeof(value), NULL);

int input{};
cin >> input;
value += input;

WriteProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)pointsAddress, &value, sizeof(value), 0);
```